# Mobile phone synchronization and backup software?

Tags: backup, mobile, phone

I would want to synchronize some data from older mobile phones that do not have Android or iOS and the software provided by the manufacturers do not have all the features that I want, mainly SMS backups.

I read about a software called [MOBILedit](http://www.mobiledit.com/) and some say that it works with my mobile phone models but it is expensive. I tried the trial version and I had to pay to unlock a phone to copy data from it.

Is there any good alternative to MOBILedit software, preferably free or open source?

I can run the software on Linux or Windows so both platforms would be good enough. I want to download data from nokia X2 and Samsung Corby and other mobile phones made around that time : years  2010 -2013 .

Comment: @Izzy I edited the question to give more details.

Comment: Thanks, yoyo! As Linux is an option: there are some packages usually in the main repos, (x)gnokii, gammu and wammu, which you could give a try. Cannot give a clear recommendation on any of those as it's too long ago I've used them – back when I still had my Nokia devices in operational mode.

Comment: Take a look at [MyPhoneExplorer](http://www.fjsoft.at/en/)